# React middleware auth component with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this app.js. I try to do an Auth component whether it simply act as a middleawre to check whether user has logged in.

```
const App = props => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="app">
                <Layout>
                <Header>
                    <Navbar />
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
                    <Auth>
                        <Route exact path='/task/:id' component={Task} />
                    </Auth>
                </Content>
                </Layout>
            </div>
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

But the strange thing is it will trigger when I visit to login and signup route.

My auth.js look like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class auth extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
        if(!user) {
            window.location = '/login'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u using redux?where is the middleware?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN it has nothing to do with redux.

Comment: What is log for this `const user = localStorage.getItem('user')`?

Comment: it depends whether my localstorage has user object or not, it doesn't matter, the problem is when I visit localhost:3000/login or localhost:3000/signup the auth component still trigger that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Routes File**

```js
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"

// Middleware
import AuthGuard from './AuthGuard'

// Pages
import HomePage from '../views/frontend/pages/HomePage'

const AppRouter  = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<p>About</p>} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<AuthGuard Component={<p>Dashboard</p>} />} />
        </Routes>
    )

}

export default AppRouter;
```

**Auth Guard File**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthGuard = () => {
    const auth = ( token != null ) ? true : null ;

    // If has token, return outlet in other case return navigate to login page

    return auth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}

export default AuthGuard
```

Answer (score 2):

> But the strange thing is it will trigger when I visit to login and signup route.

The problem is with this one.

```
<Auth>
  <Route exact path='/task/:id' component={Task} />
</Auth>
```

Your `Auth` component is getting called by default as there is no `Route` is wrapped and no condition specified for rendering.

Correct way to do this.

You should use higher order component.

```
<Route exact path='/task/:id' component={Auth(Task)} />
```

Now,this will call your `Auth` component only when your exact task path will match.

Inside of `Auth` component handled the rendering of routed component.